# ActionLink with Attribute Routing in MVC 5

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink, attributerouting

I'm having trouble with an ActionLink in MVC 5.

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Commissions", "/" + item.Id.ToString, "Commissions") 
@Html.ActionLink("View Commissions", "Index", "Commissions", New With {Key .payRollId = item.Id}, Nothing)
```

These two ActionLinks should accomplish the same thing, but I would prefer to use the second one. Unfortunately, they produce different URLs. The first creates `http://mysite/Commissions/3`. The second creates `http://mysite/Commissions?payRollId=3`.

In my Commissions controller, I have the following code:

```
    ' GET: Commissions/5
    <Route("Commissions/{payRollId:min(1)}")>
    Async Function Index(ByVal payRollId As Integer?) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If IsNothing(payRollId) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If

        Return View(Await ...query...).ToListAsync)
    End Function
```

This successfully handles the first ActionLink's URL. The second one results in a 404 error. I don't have any other RouteAttributes or mapped routes for Commissions. According to this [attribute routing article](http://www.ehsanghanbari.com/Post/114/attribute-routing-with-aspnet-mvc5), the second ActionLink should create the pretty URL (no query string) that successfully  handles the request.

What am I missing? How can I get the second ActionLink to generate the proper URL (`Commissions/3`) to match the RouteAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

This should produced the desired route:

```
<a href="~/Commissions/@item.Id">View Commissions</a>
```

This assumes you've enabled attribute based routing something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this produces `http://mysite/Commissions/Index/3` which doesn't match the RouteAttribute and results in a 404 error. Perhaps I should create another Action in the Controller, but it seems redundant. If I go with that option, I'd just change my current RouteAttribute to include `Index`.

Comment: What is the full route you want then? I assumed your controller was called CommissionsController. Is that not the case?

Comment: The full route I want is `http://mysite/Commissions/{payRollId}` where `payRollId` is an integer. Although the Action is "Index", it's omitted from the actual URL. The controller is not called CommissionsController (it's much much longer and was auto-generated with the scaffolding option).

Comment: Edit my answer to accommodate the unconventional route. So far as I can tell, the @Html.ActionLink helper won't help with unconventional (ie attribute based) routes. One could conceivably create one's own helper to do the job, but it's probably faster just to take advantage of Razor's handling base routes through the ~/ and using anchor tags directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution. I played with the controller code and found that changing the RouteAttribute to `<Route("Commissions/{payRollId:min(1)?}")>` (note the `?` at the end) allows it to handle the second URL.

I am still working on how to generate a pretty URL using the second ActionLink. I will update this answer if I work it out.